# Работа серверного приложения

Tags: php, node.js, многопоточность, веб-сервер, процесс

Я, допустим, написал одно веб-приложение на php, которое располагается на моем сервере. То есть имеется один код. Но клиентов ведь много.

Допустим, сразу 10 человек подключаются к моему серверу. И как это один единственный код обрабатывает запросы всех человек сразу? Он ведь это делает одновременно.

Я слышал, это связано с потоками и процессами, какими-то экземплярами. В общем. объясните это, пожалуйста.

А ещё объясните, чем архитектура php приложения отличается от архитектуры node.js приложения. Слышал, разница в каких-то потоках, то есть в их количестве.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Есть HTTP. Он работает по схеме "**клиент** послал *запрос* @ **сервер** *ответил*".

---

---

В случае с PHP обычно есть вебсервер. Многопоточностью занимается обычно именно он. Он принимает *запрос* и передаёт его интерпретатору PHP.

---

**Если** вебсервер использует CGI, то получив запрос, он запускает новый процесс интерпретатора PHP, передаёт ему параметры *запроса*, передаёт выведенные интерпретатором данные обратно клиенту и дожидается, пока процесс закончит работу. Параллельная обработка может происходить за счёт того, что вебсервер контролирует несколько процессов интерпретатора PHP.

Запуск каждый раз нового процесса потребляет оперативную память, разумеется. И время. Припоминаю случаи, когда слишком много параллельных клиентов приводили к слишком большому потреблению ОЗУ и слабопредсказуемым последствиям.

---

**Если** вебсервер использует FastCGI, то он заранее, при запуске, поднимает набор процессов интерпретатора PHP в особом режиме. В наборе каждый интерпретатор может быть *занят* или *свободен*.

Вебсервер, получив запрос, берёт из своего набора *свободный* процесс интерпретатора (делая его *занятым*), сообщает ему (с помощью сокетов) параметры запроса, и выдаваемый ответ передаёт пользователю, после чего *освобождает* интерпретатор.

По сравнению с CGI, процессы больше не завершаются/запускаются на каждый запрос, что уже неплохо. И процессов конечное количество. Если каждый из них ограничить по памяти, они будут потреблять предсказуемое количество ресурсов.

Но осталась другая проблема, актуальная и для CGI: код приложения обычно перед непосредственно обработкой запроса выполняет некоторую *подготовительную работу*: загружает библиотеки, настройки, создаёт системные объекты. Это довольно внушительная часть кода, которая для разных запросов приводит к одним и тем же результатам. Но эти результаты не сохраняются, а выбрасываются **в никуда** после каждого запроса. Не круто.

---

---

На этой ноте выходим из мира PHP, пропуская экзотические способы заставить PHP обслуживать запросы, и переходим к более интересным темам. Про что вы там спрашивали... NodeJS! Окей.

JavaScript исторически достаточно сильно привязан к **циклу событий**. Сам по себе он не многопоточен, программы на JS принято разделять на небольшие порции, между которыми делать всё равно нечего и можно дать поработать кому-то ещё. Поэтому очень часто код на NodeJS "общается с внешним миром" **асинхронно**: он не просто говорит "сделай Х", а **"сделай Х, и когда получишь результат, сообщи в Y, а я пойду отдыхать"**.

Действий, которые полезно выполнять асинхронно в мире веб-сайтов довольно много: ожидание поступления данных от клиента, ожидание результатов от базы данных, ожидание записи в файл, и прочая, прочая.

Вебсервер в Node.js собственный, встроенный. И поскольку он управляется непосредственно из интерпретатора, с контролем над тем, что выполнить до и после, можно заранее *один раз* подготовить объекты и выполнять запросы, не конструируя их по новой каждый раз.

Внутри Node.js крутится "цикл событий" вокруг "очереди событий" (упрощённо). Цикл событий: `{`берёт очередное событие из очереди`,` выполняет связанное с ним *действие*`}` и так по кругу, причём *действия* могут добавлять новые записи в очередь событий.

Когда запросы поступают по очереди, очередь событий не раздувается более чем на 1 запись и порядок выполнения кода в целом похож на обычный:

1. приходит запрос (в очередь!)
2. цикл событий обнаружиает пришедший запрос (из очереди!)

   - вызвал обработчик `f` для запроса
3. обработчик `f` попросил выполнить запрос в БД (в очередь!)

   - а результат передать в обработчик `g`
4. запрос в БД выполняется, ожидание, очередь событий пуста

   - но есть обработчики, поэтому процесс ещё не закончен
5. в цикл событий пришло уведомление о завершении запроса (из очереди!)

   - вызвал обработчик `g` для результатов запроса
6. обработчик `g` на основе результатов запроса составил страницу и отправил пользователю

Теперь вопрос: как Node.js выполняет несколько запросов параллельно?

Ответ: **так только кажется**. Просто из-за асинхронности код запроса разбит на отдельные небольшие кусочки, между которыми допускается ожидание. Если запросов мало, то это *реально* ожидание, а если много, то *во время ожидания можно делать что-то полезное*.

Выше описан типичный запрос простенького веб-приложения, где асинхронных действий всего два: получение запроса от вебсервера и запрос к БД. На практике их обычно больше.

В то время, как БД выполняет запрос для первого клиента, может прийти запрос от второго. Если событие о приходе **второго запроса** придёт раньше **результатов из БД для первого**, то Node.js:

- сначала обработает **второй запрос** (2.II)
- отправит **второй запрос в БД** (3.II)
- **получит данные из БД к первому запросу** (5.I), сформирует и запишет ответ первому

  - (если запросы в БД более-менее одинаковые и новых запросов нет)
- получит данные из БД ко второму запросу (5.II), сформирует и запишет ответ второму

---

И выходит, что в каждый момент времени выполняется только одно действие, но при этом **один процесс** в каждый момент времени может обслуживать **несколько клиентов**. И допускаются **долгие запросы** отдельных клиентов. К примеру, не по HTTP а, скажем, Websockets.

В CGI и FastCGI, теоретически обслуживание Websocket-соединения занимает целый процесс и не даёт ему заняться ничем другим. N процессов, создаём N соединений и ба-бах -- на запросы отвечать больше некому. Вебсервер из Node.js и другие событийные вебсерверы этим не страдают.

---

Конечно, этого может быть недостаточно. С многоядерными процессорами даже процессы Node.js может иметь смысл поднимать не поодиночке, а сразу наборами. Но какая-то единая точка должна будет раскидывать по ним запросы от клиентов. **Балансировщик нагрузки.** nginx, HAProxy, Varnish или что-то ещё.

---

Встроенный в язык вебсервер может быть и менее умным: к примеру, есть язык Ruby, в нём принято использовать интерфейс Rack (в котором обработчик запроса -- одна здоровенная **функция** из кучи частей). Этот интерфейс реализуется вебсервером Unicorn. Получив запрос, он вызывает обработчик-**функцию** и отдаёт возвращённое ею значение.

Разумеется, каждый процесс Unicorn может обслуживать только один запрос. И если он торчит "наружу" (клиенты общаются непосредственно с ним), может возникнуть проблема, если клиент *медленный*: Unicorn будет терпеливо ждать, пока клиент примет ответ, сколько бы это времени ни заняло, пока клиент кажется живым.

N процессов, N медленных клиентов и вуаля -- запросы обслуживать больше некому.

Поэтому Unicorn **всегда** размещают "наружу" за балансировщиком нагрузки, потому что у балансировщика есть собственный **буфер** в который Unicorn может **быстро** выкинуть ответ и приступить к следующему запросу, пока балансировщик своим эффективным вводом/выводом (асинхронном событийным) вдалбливает ответы даже в медленных клиентов, освободив от неблагодарной работы Unicorn.

---

---

...так, сколько килобайт я уже тут понаписал... Почти 7! Ну... думаю, вы поняли, что это довольно обширная тема.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что не поленились и хорошо объяснили

Comment: @Muller  В дополнение к ответу: на PHP есть ещё сокеты, и с появлением полной поддержки сокетов в JS (во всех совр. браузерах) - это уже перестало быть экзотическим способом обмена данных клиент-сервер. И соответсвенно при работе с сокетами исчезает проблема `код приложения обычно перед непосредственно обработкой запроса выполняет некоторую подготовительную работу` на PHP

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр а как решили проблему с тем, что активное соединение занимает весь процесс интерпретатора? (в смысле, я действительно спрашиваю, без подтекста)

Comment: @D-side , не совсем понял. Вот например пример который тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/ - в бесконечном цикле обрабатываются все соединения. Если вы про парралелизм - есть pcntl_fork , если вы про то что бесконечный цикл в PHP нехорошо - сокет можно убивать периодически (завершать скрипт), при этом автоматически создаётся новый сокет, а клиенты переподключаются.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр прочитал. Там сист. вызов `select` + отдельный процесс для сокет-соединений. Резонный ход, но склонен считать, что это тоже экзотика.

Comment: Поправка: балансировщик нагрузки перед нодой желателен, но не является обязательным. У ноды для распределения запросов по процессам есть модуль cluster.

Comment: @PavelMayorov мастер-процесс кластера тоже вполне себе является балансировщиком.

Comment: @D-side да, но он внутренний, а не внешний по отношению к ноде