# Можно ли запустить nodejs и python сервера на одном порту?

Tags: python, node.js, django, сервер, koa.js

Хочу чтобы одни странице на сайте генерировал `koa.js` для `nodejs`, а другие `django` для `python`. Например,

На запрос `GET /nodejs` должен отвечать nodejs, а на `GET /python` - python.

Можно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: Через третий прокси-сервер nginx устроит?

Comment: Порт - по своей природе тот ещё собственник, добавить пачку слушателей нельзя. Но прокси может, правда Ваша схема попахивает изысканным извращением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На один порт повесить нельзя, можно сделать reverse proxy который будет переадресовывать запросы на NodeJS и Python, но тогда NodeJS и Python должны висеть на своих портах на которые и будет идти переадресация, я бы сделал основной сервер на NodeJS в котором бы сделал редирект на Python, если система nix то можно даже сделать на Unix-сокетах, будет быстрее и меньше грузить процессор.

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно. А можно про Unix-сокеты подробнее? Как с их помощью можно это сделать?

Comment: есть в документации к ноде - https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_backlog_callback , с питоном особо не дружу но поиск говорит что поддержка есть, в кратце это почти тоже самое что по сети, просто вместо сервера указывается специальная виртуальная папка в системе, которая работает как буффер, поэтому там очень низкая задержка и не грузить процессор обработкой TCP/IP пакетов

Comment: node многопоточная, python однопоточный скорее всего подразумевается. Уверены в том что стоит так проксировать через ноду?

Comment: node однопоточная

Answer (score 3):

В продакшене "серверы приложений" (то, что непосредственно хостит приложение с интерпретатором) обычно не торчат наружу. Обычно их прикрывают **"обратным прокси"**.

## Зачем?

- Затем, что **немалая часть запросов к приложениям**, по-хорошему, просто запрашивает файлы, **без дополнительной логики и проверок**. Хорошо, если сервер приложения, скажем, написан в большой степени на каком-нибудь С, и может с такими запросами разбираться даже не спрашивая интерпретатор. Но обычно для обеспечения хорошего настраиваемого интерфейса сервер плотно сшивается с интерпретатором и работает существенно медленнее чего-нибудь, что написано само по себе на С или чём-то сопоставимом. Но это уже зависит от реализации конкретных серверов.

  Некоторые серверы приложений вообще изначально не спроектированы, чтобы торчат наружу без защиты. Не потому что их легко взломать, а потому что *злонамеренный клиент может их уронить*. Сценарии описывал [в одном из своих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556929/181100) ранее.
- Ещё затем, чтобы можно было **поднять несколько процессов одного приложения и раскидывать запросы между ними**. Это называется "балансировщик нагрузки". Когда нагрузка становится большой, эти процессы можно даже по разным машинам разнести.
- Ещё ради **кэширования** частых запросов с одинаковыми ответами. Хотя настройка этого редко обходится без приключений.
- Ещё ради **защиты**. Вебсервера, типично работающие в роли балансировщиков, обычно крайне устойчивы к нагрузкам сами по себе, и могут быть в этом направлении развиты дополнительными усилиями путём настройки или добавления дополнительных модулей, которые проверяют запросы и (возможно) банят нарушителей.

В основном я встречаю в их роли:

- nginx (популярный вариант, очень много всего умеет, много дополнительных модулей)
- Varnish (продвигается больше как кэширующий прокси, не очень популярен, но быстр)
- HAProxy (преимущественно балансировщик, используется во многих крупных проектах)

...и **типичный случай**: когда нужный порт (80?) слушает прокси, и получает запросы, соответственно, прокси, и получая запросы, прокси делает одно из:

- ...обслуживает их сам (из кэша, файловой системы или согласно правилам в конфиге)
- ...передаёт запрос другому HTTP-серверу (опять же согласно правилам в конфиге: с другим вебсервером он общается по Unix-сокету или сетевому соединению)

  - Для сервера приложения обычно запрос выглядит, как пришедший с адреса `127.0.0.1` (с точки зрения соединения), это обычно исправляют добавлением в передаваемый запрос заголовка `X-Forwarded-For`, куда пишется настоящий адрес клиента.
  - ...потом принимает ответ от другого сервера и передаёт обратно клиенту.