# Можно ли использовать вебсокеты на чистом php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, websocket

Возможно ли использование вебсокетов без phpdaemon,  node.is,  пользуясь только возможностями php, is, jquery?

Comment: Не могу сказать что дубликат, но [я как-то писал простыню на смежную тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556929/181100).

Comment: Возможно хоть Websocket сервер, хоть клиент.

Comment: Пример сервера: http://грибовы.рф/?p=2771

Comment: Пример клиента: http://грибовы.рф/?p=2943

Comment: Да это возможно. Подробней можно почитать тут :[Делаем вебсокеты на PHP с нуля ](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/)