# В чем разница между Passenger, Puma, Webrick и др

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Добрый день, стоит задача в девелопмент-среде подключить к Rails-проекту nginx. В статьях в сети заметил, что используются различные связки nginx с другими серверами (встренными?). Я так понял, что nginx работает только в связке (с\на\под другим сервером приложений)? Не пойму в чем принципиальная разница между Puma, Webrick, Phusion Passenger, и как они взаимодействуют с nginx? Какие еще связки для рельсы с nginx существуют? Какая предпочтительнее?

з.ы. рельсу только учу
з.ы.ы. спасибо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Всё просто. Но много.

Вебсервер разделяется на:

- **сервер приложения**

  - занимается непосредственно кодом приложения
  - в случае Ruby on Rails любой Rack-совместимый (WEBrick, Puma, и т. п.): он принимает в качестве приложения какой-нибудь объект на Ruby с методом `call` (так называемый Rack handler), в аргументах получает среду запроса, а вернуть должен массив вида `[статус_код, заголовки, массив_строк_кусков_тела_ответа]`
- **обратный прокси** (в вашем случае nginx, видел ещё Varnish, HAProxy, Cherokee), который при различных обстоятельствах может быть также:

  - **балансировщиком нагрузки** — чтобы можно было поднять несколько серверов приложения (возможно даже на разных машинах)
  - **сервером раздачи статики** — поскольку такой сервер обычно гораздо эффективнее для этой задачи, чем любой Rack-совместимый сервер. Причём `nginx` может раздавать статику как сам (если обнаруживает по пути запроса файл в файловой системе), так и по указанию в ответе с сервера приложения (заголовком `X-Accel-Redirect`, при котором статика отправляется *вместо ответа*).

Соответственно... о Rack-совместимых серверах.

- **Webrick** — просто бесхитростный вебсервер на Ruby. Медленный, однопоточный, зато в стандартной библиотеке и не требует установки каких бы там ни было гемов.
- **Unicorn** — спроектирован для быстрой обработки запросов, однопоточный, но многопроцессный. Был рекомендованным для Heroku сервером *ранее*, но... Уязвим для медленных клиентов: если клиент медленно принимает ответ, Unicorn будет продолжать "кормить его с ложечки" и не сможет обслуживать другие запросы. Посему для размещения в интернете обратный прокси для него практически обязателен.
- **Puma** — сравнительно новый (2011) вебсервер, умеющий и многопроцессность, и многопоточность (для каждого входящего запроса создаётся новый поток), от медленных клиентов он не страдает, поскольку может обслуживать нескольких одновременно. Heroku рекомендует на своих серверах пользоваться именно им. Может работать в несколько процессов на единственном Unix-сокете.
- **Thin** — в целом, сопоставим по функциональности с Puma, использует событийный IO на основе EventMachine. В многопроцессном режиме создаёт несколько сокетов, раскидывать запросы между ними должен отдельный балансировщик, например nginx.
- **Passenger** — тоже богатый на разные фичи вебсервер, сопоставим с Puma, местами даже превосходит его, но самые вкусные фишки (перезапуск без простоя, многопоточность) есть только в коммерческой версии. Ресурсопотребление довольно эффективное, а кроме как на Ruby, можно запускать приложения ещё и на Node.js. Есть платная поддержка (для тех, кому она нужна).

Выбор непростой, каждый случай стоит рассматривать отдельно. Puma сгодится практически всегда, но в ряде случае можно увеличить эффективность, перейдя на что-нибудь другое.

С nginx они все взаимодействуют одинаково, как с обратным прокси: сидят где-нибудь на недоступном из внешнего мира адресе (`localhost`, Unix domain socket или другой хост во внутренней сети), запросы получают только от nginx, отвечают ему же.

---

См. также: [Работа серверного приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556929/181100).