# Коннект по websocket, инициализируемый клиентом

Tags: php, клиент-сервер, websocket

Пытаюсь написать связку по WebSocket-соединению между клиентом и сервером.
И если по клиенту всё прекрасно разжевано на `learn.javascript.ru`, то насчет php вообще ничего конкретного.

Вот [пример](http://php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php) с известного сайта `php.net`:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<h2>Соединение TCP/IP</h2>\n";

/* Получаем порт сервиса WWW. */
$service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

/* Получаем  IP адрес целевого хоста. */
$address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
```

В нем есть два примера, два типа: сервер-сервер и сервер-клиент.
Мне нужно второе.
Допустим, что код сверху лежит на моём сервере, откуда пользователь загрузил страничку. После загрузки страницы происходит запрос на скрипт по вебсокету, так это будет работать у меня.
Но смотрю на код и вижу, что в примере коннект происходит по url.  И не могу понять, это url моего ресурса и мы берем ip подключения, который приходит от запроса клиента, чтобы потом в последующем использовать его для привязки WebSocket'а, или мы коннектимся к другому серверу вообще?

Честно говоря, вообще плыву от websocket на php, а хочется написать их на чистом php.
Был бы очень и очень благодарен за простенькую реализацию, которая бы по вебсокиту просто выводила то же самое сообщение, которое мы послали по соединению на клиенте. Тогда всё было бы просто и понятно.
Никак всё не могу разобраться с этим...

Comment: Вам может быть интересен [один из моих старых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556929/181100).

Comment: @D-side действительно, задавался этим вопросом совсем недавно, думал даже сюда его задать, но пока повременил. А Вы тут как тут) Спасибо. Эх, жаль с самим вопросом некому помочь.