# Как перезапустить PHP в режиме CGI?

Tags: php, cgi

Через `phpinfo` нашел и поправил конфиг под себя, однако как перезапустить PHР, чтоб он перечитал настройки не смог - в инете море инфы про Apache и FastCGI - а про этот режим найти ответ не смог :(.

Comment: Связано: [Работа серверного приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556929/181100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас там правда CGI, то для обработки каждого запроса и так запускается новый процесс PHP. Перезапуск PHP в таком сценарии не имеет смысла. Настройки будут считываться из файлов при каждом запросе.

Comment: А из каких файлов ? Я видел в папке с доменом php.ini, и туда писал, и  в глобальный конфиг для CGI

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov [на сайте PHP об этом целая страница есть](http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.file.php).